# Delphi Records - creating a pointer to it

Tags: pointers, delphi, record, pascal

I'm trying to see how I can create a pointer to a simple record.

I have searched for similar topics before posting but it's quite confusing.

I create A & B of which are actual Records.
I then have a variable C which I want to be just a 'pointer to this record'.
I don't want C to store its own value but just a pointer to either A or B.
But whenever C is read/written to,
it's actually being written to either A or B, whichever C is pointing to.

In other words, it's like a pointer to an Object, but I don't need an Object in my case.

Using Delphi 10.3 & 10.4 (if there's any difference), please highlight.

The code below results in Access Violation on first ShowMessage.

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
type
  TMyRecord = record
    Field1 : integer;
  end;
var
  A : TMyRecord;
  B : TMyRecord;
  C : ^TMyRecord; // how to declare this as a pointer?
begin
  A.Field1 := 1;
  B.Field1 := 2;

  C^ := A;  // psuedo code to point to A
  A.Field1 := 3;
  showmessage( C^.Field1.ToString );   // result is 3
  C.Field1 := 4;
  showmessage( A.Field1.ToString );   // result is 4

  C^ := B;  // psuedo code to point to A
  C.Field1 := 5;
  showmessage( B.Field1.ToString );   // result is 5
  // anything to free here to avoid memory loss?
end;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`C` should contain address of `A`, so make

```
C := @A;
```

and the rest of code will work as needed.

Also note that `C.Field1` is implicit dereference, it really works as  `C^.Field1`

---

For now

```
C^ := A;
```

denotes assigning contents of `A` record to memory region addressed by `C`, but this memory  is not allocated - that's why access violation occurs. (To allocate memory, you can make `New(C)`, but this is not needed for your purposes)

Also if you are going to actively use pointer to record, you can define type

```
PMyRecord  =  ^TMyRecord;
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, literally and otherwise. :)